# How to set cell spacing with collapsed borders using inline CSS

Tags: html, css, html-table

I know that "border", "cellpadding" and "cellspacing" have been used for table properties.

When using css instead, I have read that the style attribute "border-spacing:", e.g. `border-spacing: 3;` has no effect if  `border-collapse: collapse`.

How can I create tables with spaces between cells and collapsed borders, with inline css? I am using inline css for various reasons.

The code I am currently using is:

```html
<table style='border: 1px solid black; border-spacing: 5; border-collapse: collapse'>
  <tr>
    <th>a</th>
    <th>b</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>c</td>
    <td>d</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Desired output:
https://pasteboard.co/KhHooTH.png

Current output:
https://pasteboard.co/KhHoRDK.png

I cannot show images inline as as my reputation is low.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to do it inline, you'll also have to add the style to the cells.

*E.g.:*

```
<table style='border: 1px solid black; border-spacing: 5; border-collapse: collapse'>
    <tr style='border: 1px solid black;'>
        <th style='border: 1px solid black;'>a</th>
        <th>b</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style='border: 1px solid black;'>c</td>
        <td>d</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Set as answer for mentioning that it must be added to each cell. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The following ***embedded `CSS` snippet*** can be used to set the cell spacing w/ collapsed borders.

```html
<table style="border:1px solid black;border-collapse:collapse;">
  <tr>
    <th style="border:1px solid red;">Table Header</th>
    <th style="border:1px solid red;">Table Header</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="border:1px solid red;">Table cell 1</td>
    <td style="border:1px solid red;">Table cell 2</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td style="border:1px solid red;">Table cell 3</td>
    <td style="border:1px solid red;">Table cell 4</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `rules="all"` to table (to have all borders) and then set padding to every cell (if you want inline styling, you can do it too):

```css
.myTable TR TH, .myTable TR TD {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<table class="myTable" style='border: 1px solid black;' rules="all">
  <tr>
    <th>a</th>
    <th>b</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>c</td>
    <td>d</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks. I suppose the options are either a <style> section as you suggest, or adding to each cell, as per the other answers.